# Unable to grab custom header from angularjs failure $resource callback

Tags: angularjs, callback

I have this `$resource` call :

```
var account = Accounts.get(function() {

 //success - do something fancy

    }, function(data, status, headers){

        //error - grab x_something header

    });
```

In the failure callback when an `HTTP 403 error` returning with custom "`x_something`" header (I can see it in the network traffic in Chrome network tab) - I can't find it in `data.headers()` , or in any other place

Anyone know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
var account = Accounts.get(function() {

 //success - do something fancy

    }, function(httpResponse){

        //error - grab x_something header
        var x_something = httpResponse.headers("x_something");
    });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qhda7/)

In this demo, I log the `Content-Type` header, it would be similar to any custom header.